# In Django is it possible to make database queries without having to render a template in view?

Tags: php, mysql, django

I want to update existing information under an account registered in a mysql table.

Is there a way to dynamically create questions within the same template file and still unique database queries like in PHP but in Django?

Because up to my knowledge it seems like it only works through forms which requires their own template/html files to render before queries can be made.

Comment: You can query the database any where, they don't need to be tied to templates or views. I frequently use django  in stand alone (CLI) scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you can make queries in Django without rendering any templates.

What you say about Django queries requiring a template rendering to be made is only true in some contexts. [Django querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), which means they are not run before they are needed. It means that if you create a query like this:

```
Person.objects.all()
```

It's not executed until some of the fields of it are needed. If you pass to a template the previous query under the name people and then iterate it like this:

```
{% for person in people %}
    {{ person.age }}
{% endfor %}
```

The query is only executed when rendering the template.

For other kinds of queries, like this:

```
person_count = Person.objects.count()
Person.objects.filter(age=39).update(age=40)
```

Those queries are executed in a SELECT COUNT(*) and UPDATE fashion immediately onto the database.

Comment: So I have this html file where I ask the user some questions. How do I execute that last update query block you have when the user clicks submit?

Comment: When the user clicks submit, you will redirect it to a url (which can be the same as the one he got the questions, but using POST instead of GET), you will pass some parameters (maybe some POST parameters to determine the query) and then on the view method you will determine the query, update the results and redirect the user to a special url, that's how I see things...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question clearly.

If you don't want to render templates for a request, you could just make a javascript post request from one of your templates and do your update on the database and just return a JSON response

Or

If you don't want to use templates/views at all, you could use the django shell and run your queries. you can access the shell by this command

```
./manage.py shell
```

Comment: Is it good practice to use javascript/JSON to make those queries while you already have a functioning Django framework. Doesn't it seem a bit unnecessarily heavy?

Comment: Well, If you have to create more questions, you need a form where you can feed data, which can be posted to the server using javascript.

If you don't want to use the form, if you might just need it for the admin purpose, you can still write a python script to create more questions which can be run in the django environment. Even more, you can simply enable the django admin for that Model and create questions as need comes !!